# 'T' does not contain a definition for 'Foo' and the best extension method overload requires a receiver of type 'IType'

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a code like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public interface IMyString
{
    string Id {get;set;}
};

public class MyString : IMyString
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IMyString> WithId(this IEnumerable<IMyString> source, string id)
    {
        return source.Where(x => x.Id == id);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    private static List<T> GetMyStrings<T>(string key, List<T> input)
        where T: IMyString
    {
        return input.WithId(key).ToList();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var foo = new List<MyString>{ new MyString { Id = "yes"}, new MyString { Id = "no" } };
        var result = GetMyStrings("yes", foo);
        var result2 = foo.WithId("no");
        Console.WriteLine(result2);
    }
}
```

Why does `input.WithId(key).ToList()` cause a syntax error, while `foo.WithId("no")` is OK? Is there a way to make the method `GetMyStrings` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WithId<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string id) 
    where T : IMyString
{
    return source.Where(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Without the context of your code it is a little difficult to help too much, but your type constraints for the two methods are different. You have two options:

**Option 1:**

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> WithId<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string id) where T: IMyString
    {
        return source.Where(x => x.Id == id);
    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
private static List<IMyString> GetMyStrings(string key, List<IMyString> input)
{
    return input.WithId(key).ToList();
}

public static void Main()
{
    var foo = new List<IMyString>{ new MyString { Id = "yes"}, new MyString { Id = "no" } };
    var result = GetMyStrings("yes", foo);
    var result2 = foo.WithId("no");
    Console.WriteLine(result2);
}
```

Here is a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CPi6Vx) with the second option as a working piece of code: